# Home button not working after being pressed

Tags: java, android

I want to access my home page after being pressed. The problem is that after the home button is pressed, you will not be able to go back to it. Despite using the `return root` function, it still doesn't allow me to access the page after being clicked. [This picture shows how I am still pressing on the home button but nothing comes up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoyUZ.jpg)

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Here is my HomeViewModel:

```js
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    public HomeViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mText.setValue("This is home");
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

Here is my HomeFragment:

```js
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.home_fragment);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }}
```

Here is my MainDashboard Activity:

```js
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/darker_grey"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/fragment2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:paddingBottom="38sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment2"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="200dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="358dp" />
```

Here is my MainDashboardClass:

```js
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__dashboard);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,  R.id.fragment2);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
```

Here is my Navigaion Graph:

```js
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home2">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_account"
        android:name="com.login.diamondcharnea.ui.Dashboard_Elements.Account.AccountFragment"
        android:label="account.layout"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_favorites"
        android:name="com.login.diamondcharnea.ui.Dashboard_Elements.Favorites.FavoritesFragment"
        android:label="favorites.layout"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_favorites" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home2"
        android:name="com.login.diamondcharnea.ui.Dashboard_Elements.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Home.layout"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_browse"
        android:name="com.login.diamondcharnea.ui.Dashboard_Elements.Browse.BrowseFragment"
        android:label="Browse.layout"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_browse" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_bag"
        android:name="com.login.diamondcharnea.ui.Dashboard_Elements.bag.BagFragment"
        android:label="Bag.layout"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_bag" />
</navigation>
```

And here is my BottomNavMenu:

```js
<item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/diamond"
        android:title="@string/title_home"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_browse"
        android:icon="@drawable/iconfinder_search_172546"
        android:title="Browse" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_bag"
        android:icon="@drawable/shopping_bag"
        android:title="@string/bag" />

    <item
        android:title="@string/favorites"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_favorites"
        android:icon="@drawable/heart" />

    <item
        android:title="@string/account"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/user" />

</menu>
```

Comment: provide the code of the main activity , which contains NavController

Comment: Sorry, I have now attached this file.

Comment: and the navigation graph ?

Comment: I have attached this file as well and sorry good sir, I am new at StackOverflow.

Comment: please make sure your question is precise , if possible send an image result

Comment: because from you code one can not easily understand what went wrong and you quest is not quiet clear. just saying

Comment: No, I understand. To be honest, it's quite hard to put my problem into words, so I did the best I could. And I also added the image, I hope it helps.

Comment: so when you click the home button you can't got to the other fragments ??

Comment: When I click the home button, it doesn't go to the home button fragment. Nothing comes up, it's almost as if there is nothing there.

Comment: check your view model and make sure there is data coming from the view model.

Comment: please if you can send your HomeViewModel it will go a long way to help me see what is up with the home fragment

Comment: Hey, I have attached the view model.

Comment: Hey good sir, i have figured it out. it was a small mistake in the Mobile_Navigation.xml. I added a 2 at the end of my ID, and it threw off my code. Thanks for the assist.